# How to test for arguments for a pattern that is of a positive Integer OR Infinity so that both filter through to the definition on RHS?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, filtering, conditional, argument-patterns

How can I filter an argument of a function so that definition works on positive `Integers (y >= 0)` or `Infinity`? It will actually have two arguments the other only needing only to be a positive integer. But first I tried only filtering both arguments for positive integers with mixed results. The Only filters that worked were those in which `Conditional` was applied but all `PatternTests`-s failed. I got same results when I only examined for Infinity. Various defnitions were attempted separately to make certain I am using correct approach before combining one argument with positive integer or infinity. I have read all the tutorials, guides, and official documentation of all applicable native symbols and read plenty of articles on here but for some reason i cant seem to get `?` to work on anonymous functions or native functions when attached to an argument pattern.

This is the simplified code I attempted in which `/;` works but not `?`.

```
Quiet@Remove@"Global`*"

(* pattern filtering for positive integers *)
fxy1[x_Integer /; x >= 0, y_Integer /; y >= 0] := {{{x, y}}};
fxy1[___] := "fxy1";
fxy2[x_Integer /; (x >= 0), y_Integer /; (y >= 0)] := {{{x, y}}};
fxy2[___] := "fxy2";
fxy3[x_Integer?(# >= 0) &, y_Integer?(# >= 0) &] := {{{x, y}}};
fxy3[___] := "fxy3";
fxy4[x_Integer?(x >= 0) &, y_Integer?(y >= 0) &] := {{{x, y}}};
fxy4[___] := "fxy4";

(* integer filtering tests *)
fxy1[1, 2]
fxy1[1, -2]
fxy2[1, 2]
fxy2[1, -2]
fxy3[1, 2]
fxy3[1, -2]
fxy4[1, 2]
fxy4[1, -2]

(* pattern filtering for positive infinity *)
inf1[y_?SameQ[#, Infinity] &] := {{{y}}};
inf2[y_?MatchQ[#, Infinity] &] := {{{y}}};
inf3[y_?(y == Infinity) &] := {{{y}}};
inf4[y_?(y === Infinity) &] := {{{y}}};
inf5[y_ /; SameQ[y, Infinity]] := {{{y}}};
inf6[y_ /; MatchQ[y, Infinity]] := {{{y}}};
inf7[y_ /; (y == Infinity)] := {{{y}}};
inf8[y_ /; (y === Infinity)] := {{{y}}};

(* infinity matching tests *)
{inf1[Infinity], inf2[Infinity], inf3[Infinity], inf4[Infinity], 
 inf5[Infinity], inf6[Infinity], inf7[Infinity], inf8[Infinity]}
{inf1[1], inf2[2], inf3[3], inf4[4], inf5[5], inf6[6], inf7[7], 
 inf8[8]}
```

**My questions are...**

1. Why didn't any of my `PatternTest`-s work?`
2. How can I combine one argument to be `positive Integer OR positive Infinity`?

Comment: `foo[x : _Integer?Positive | Infinity] := x`?

Comment: For a pattern test with `&`, note the parentheses: `f[x_?(test[#] &)]...`

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for prompt response. (1) I sometimes see  `&` placed just outside last parenthesis. does this mean ampersand may have a little wiggle room at times?  (2) did you mean `Nonnegative` for for the value `x >= 0` because  `Positive`  gives `False` for `0`. I see you did not underscore arg `y` and i understand why you did that but i guess i missed that because other languages may be a little flexible with how one defines functions but they are strict on syntax.  If I needed an Integer >= 5 is this `PatternTest` correct? `fn[x_Integer?(#>=5&)]:=Row[{x, " >= 5"}]`.

Comment: `doo[x_Integer] := x /; (x > 0 || x == \[Infinity])` and test: `{doo[2.3], doo[-2], doo[0], doo[2], \[Infinity]}`

Comment: (1) `&` has a low precedence and often needs parentheses outside; `=` and `;` have a lower precedence, and in the body of a pure function, they need to have parentheses around them inside the `&`: `(n=0; x=#)&`. (2) I coded the test in question 2, "positive integer OR positive infinity". You can use `Nonnegative` iinstead. (3) `x : pat` is the syntax for [`Pattern[x, pat]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html); but do not miss the last bullet point under "Details" for an explanation of the syntactic sugar `x_`. (4) And `x_Integer?(#>=5&)` looks correct to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 i thought you might like to see the working lhs to this definition. it prolly took you 2 minutes to write down what took me days studying docs and articles here to try and try to learn more about the little details that make all the difference. thanks again.

`fnh[n_Integer?(NonNegative[#] &), 
   h : _Integer?NonNegative | Infiity] := {{{n, h}}}; 
fnh[1, -\[Infinity]] 
fnh[1, notinfiinity] 
fnh[1, \[Infinity]]`